# Can I use a Azure Data Factory endpoint to stream the data from a pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, grafana

Is it possible to pass data from a pipeline and stream it through an Azure Data Factory endpoint? The idea is to get data from a query in CosmosDB and pass it to an endpoint to get the info in a Grafana instance.

I wondered that it may exist a pre designed endpoint in Data factory to pass the data directly

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Didn't tried anything in special, I know that a REST service can be used to hit an endpoint but you have to create it. My wonder if I can get the same result without creating that specific endpoint @PratikLad

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a wrong tool for your job. You use ADF when you for example copy to and from a REST endpoint. ADF is for orchestration and not a streaming tool; it doesn't provide built-in functionality for exposing data as a service endpoint. For this you can write a function that queries from cosmos db and serves a midpoint between cosmosdb and grafana. Another way could be to set your blob storage (where your cosmos db data hits) as a streaming input for a service like ASA, and then stream it to Grafana (you can use functions output of ASA to stream to Grafana). Whereas cosmos db is supported as an output, unfortunately you cannot stream directly from cosmos db using ASA.

See this q here: [Grafana as Azure Stream Analytics output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69867126/grafana-as-azure-stream-analytics-output) (it suggests using ADX which might work)

Note: Azure monitor is also supported as a plugin for Grafana [Grafana Azure Monitor plugin](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-azure-monitor-datasource/)

Azure API management and Web Apps are normally the services used to expose a REST endpoint and manage them.